# stop React-select from opening it's menu on right click (onContextMenu)

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have this code structure:

2 React select's wrapped with a div, (it's on element which is then mapped over a list)

```
<div onContextMenu={openContextMenu}>
 <Select />
 <Select />
</div>
```

The issue is when I click right mouse button to open the context menu select menu is being open!
As I understand `React-select` uses `onMouseDown` event to open is dropdown menu

How do I prevent it from opening ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
I've got a solution!

1. Make the `<Select />` controlled by using `menuIsOpen` prop.
2. Utilize `onClick` event *(Which only registers the left click)*

```
export const ControlledSelect = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const [ visible, setVisible ] = useState(false);

  useOutsideClick(ref, () => {
    setVisible(false);
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={ ref } onClick={ handleClick }>
      <Select { ...props } menuIsOpen={ visible } />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And a custom `useOutsideClick` hook, which runs a callback when you click outside the component.

```
export function useOutsideClick(ref, callback) {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      callback();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  });
}
```